# Google analytics users and sessions are not increasing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-analytics, google-search

I am using google analytics in my asp.net mvc 5 and I am a new one to this. I have created a tracking Id and I have inserted the generated script to my layout page header(the script is saved in a separate file and imported using scrip tag). Now in my google analytics dashboard I can see the active user and it's showing the correct information. But in audiance section the user and session always remains only 1 even if in real-time I can see it's 10 or 20. In which area I am doing wrong can you please help me to point out. TIA.

Comment: How long is "always" ? GA takes up to 24 hours processing time for standard reports.

Comment: only 12 hours has been spent yet. but how come it shows 1 user 1 session from UC browser